# Are client-side raster colour-ramps possible?

Tags: openlayers, wms, style, web-mapping, browser

For web portals visualising single-band raster information (such as bathymetry or elevation), is it possible nowadays to have a colour map applied to the data in the browser (instead of server-side)?

Hopefully this would facilitate adaptive colour ramps (stretching to the range corresponding to the data extent that is displayed in the window, maximising visual contrast/discriminability); it might also make the server more efficient (compared to having styling applied by the back-end on the fly) and reduce storage/egress costs (compared to RGB).

In particular, can it be done (for extremely large rasters) with WMS and openlayers? Or is it something that requires extensive custom code, and non-standard interfaces/protocols?

Comment: The answer to these kinds of "is it possible" questions is generally "yes", but they tend to be closed as too broad.

Comment: Yes, see extreme example of client side DEM data manipulation for relief shading: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/shaded-relief.html. Color ramps would be much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Possible: yes.

I do this with a combination of [`georaster`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/georaster) and [`@visx/legend`](https://airbnb.io/visx/docs/legend) with relatively small (less than 10 MB) GeoTIFFs, displayed within a Leaflet map with [`react-leaflet`](https://preview.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet/v/0.3.0).

[image]

Doubtless there are many other ways to achieve this.

Comment: This was introduce in [this commit](https://github.com/GeoTIFF/georaster/commit/5a7d814) in georaster 1.5.3, june 2020